# Parsing data on multiple strings in R

Tags: r, grepl

I am trying to write a code that will parse through a single column that contains several pieces of information. For example, say I have the following data frame called df:

```
  ids             info
1 101       red;circle
2 103      circle;blue
3 122        red;green
4 102 circle;red;green
5 213             blue
6 170         red;blue
```

When I run table(df) you get the following:

```
    table(df)
         info
    ids   blue circle;blue circle;red;green red;blue red;circle
      101    0           0                0        0          1
      102    0           0                1        0          0
      103    0           1                0        0          0
      122    0           0                0        0          0
      170    0           0                0        1          0
      213    1           0                0        0          0
         info
    ids   red;green
      101         0
      102         0
      103         0
      122         1
      170         0

  213         0
```

What I'd like to do is 1. Break up the info column into 2 columns, one for shape and one for color and  2. Assign any id that has more than one color to be "multicolored". So I have written the following:

```
df$shape <- as.character(df$info)
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  if (grepl("circle",df$info[i])==TRUE) {
    df$shape[i] <- "circle" 
  } else if (grepl("circle",df$info[i])==FALSE) {
    df$shape[i]<-NA}
}
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  if (grepl(";",df$info[i])==TRUE) {
    df$info[i] <- "Multicolored" 
  } else {df$info[i]<-df$info[i]}
}
```

From this code I get the output:

```
df
  ids         info  shape
1 101 Multicolored circle
2 103 Multicolored circle
3 122 Multicolored   <NA>
4 102 Multicolored circle
5 213         blue   <NA>
6 170 Multicolored   <NA>
```

As my code is written, it is saying that an instance like `101 red;circle` is multicolored when in fact it is not, just red and a circle. What is the correct way of parsing this data when "circle" can appear in the info column at the beginning, middle, or end. Any and all suggestions welcome, and thanks!

Comment: Do you only have one shape?

Comment: @AnandaMahto at the moment yes, I only have one shape, but could easily have multiple shapes. Another instance I could have is an entry like '203 circle' so there would be no color, just a shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this type of problem it might make sense to split the strings on `;` and then work with vectors of character strings.  For example,

```
mystrings <- strsplit(df$info,";")
getStrings <- function(x,s,none=NA_character_,multiple="Multicolored")
   switch(sum(x%in%s)+1,none,x[x%in%s],multiple,multiple)
df$shape <- sapply(mystrings,FUN=getStrings,s=c("circle"))
df$color <- sapply(mystrings,FUN=getStrings,s=c("red","green","blue"))
```

I personally find this approach easier than trying to work with pure regular expressions and if statements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using 'switch' was something I had not thought of. I'm still relatively new to R and that will be a function I use often.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the answer by @farnsy, but I'd like to post my solution as well which is fundamentally similar, but does not require you to specify the colours (by assuming that all non-shapes are colours).

```
# Load the data
df <- read.table(textConnection('ids             info
1 101       red;circle
2 103      circle;blue
3 122        red;green
4 102 circle;red;green
5 213             blue
6 170         red;blue'),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Split your column.
split.col <- strsplit(df$info,';')
# Specify which words are considered shapes.
shapes <- c('circle') # Could include more
# Find which rows had shapes.
df$shape <- sapply(split.col, function(x) x[match(shapes,x)[1]]) # Only selct one shape
# The rest must be colours, count them.
num.colours <- sapply(split.col, function(x) length(setdiff(x, shapes)))
df$multicoloured <- num.colours > 1

df
#   ids             info  shape multicoloured
# 1 101       red;circle circle         FALSE
# 2 103      circle;blue circle         FALSE
# 3 122        red;green   <NA>          TRUE
# 4 102 circle;red;green circle          TRUE
# 5 213             blue   <NA>         FALSE
# 6 170         red;blue   <NA>          TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
 pat1 <- paste0(c("red","blue", "green"), collapse="|")
shape1 <- gsub(paste(pat1, ";", sep="|"), "", df$info)
shape1[shape1==''] <- NA
df[,c("info", "shape")] <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
                Map(`c`, lapply(regmatches(df$info, gregexpr(pat1, df$info)), function(x)   {
             if(length(x)>1) "Multicolored" else x}), shape1)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

 df
 #  ids         info  shape
 #1 101          red circle
 #2 103         blue circle
 #3 122 Multicolored   <NA>
 #4 102 Multicolored circle
 #5 213         blue   <NA>
 #6 170 Multicolored   <NA>
```